# How to serialize a json containing LAZY associations

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, serialization, jackson

I am having an `Person` entity which has `@ManyToOne` association with `Contact` entity with fetch type LAZY. I am using spring-boot to expose REST API. One of my POST call contains nested JSON to save the parent entity `Person` along with association `Contact`

Since `Contact` fetch type is LAZY, I am encountering into following exception

```
    ERROR 17415 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.rest.RestResultObject["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.model.Person["contact"]->com.example.model.Contact_$$_jvst8d1_4["handler"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.rest.RestResultObject["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.model.Person["contact"]->com.example.model.Contact_$$_jvst8d1_4["handler"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
```

Without changing Contact to EAGER. Is there any best way to solve this problem?

**Updated:**

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String rno;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Contact contact;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {
    private long id;
    private String info;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Person> persons;
}
```

Comment: could you please add code for person & contact?

Comment: @MarufHassan Updated my post

Answer (score 5):

I have added the following things

- @Entity on each object
- Change `long` to `Long` in id, this will help you if you use spring data JPA
- add `@Id` to declare id as primary key
- `@JsonBackReference` & `@JsonManagedReference` to avoid infinite loop by Jackson

Person class

```
@Entity
public class Person {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 private String name;

 private String rno;

 @JsonManagedReference
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Contact contact;

 //setter & getter
```

}

Contact class

```
@Entity
public class Contact {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 private String info;

 @JsonBackReference
 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contact")
 private List<Person> persons;

 //setter & getter
}
```

and add a dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and finally add a new config

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomBigDecimalDeserialization() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToDisable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.modules(new Hibernate5Module());
        }

    };
}
}
```

Comment: With this solution we don't get the data for the associate entities. Do you know how can we get that ?

Comment: @OneToMany by default lazy. Use fetch type eager on this annotation.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working in my case. Would you like to take a look at code here: https://github.com/JavaHelper/issue-jackson-boot

Comment: Also, I found Swagger-fox doesn't works well, gives `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: Also, with this appraoch dates are coming like "createdDate": {
                "epochSecond": 1565115275,
                "nano": 767000000
            },
            "lastUpdateDate": {
                "epochSecond": 1565115275,
                "nano": 767000000
            },

Comment: https://github.com/maruf571/MyExample-tmp 

Somehow, I am not able to push new branch on your repo.

Comment: I've reported issue there. Could you please guide me how can we fixed that ? Also, could you let me know what changes did you do?

Comment: Change set to list and fix Jason reference annotations

Comment: Thanks, issue still stays the same 1) Swagger can't be launch 2) Pagination endpoint doesn't associated entity data. Could you check on those ?

Comment: I must say it is not a solution, it just ignores to object that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, most likely, is related to transaction processing. JSON serialization is executed out of transaction scope. If so, the easiest solution (not necessarily the best from the architectural point of view) is to create the service that wrap the entity loading (dedicated for  REST operations) and perform "delazyfication" of related data, e.g. (the key element is  `@Transactional` anotation).

```
@Sevice
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class DataReaderServiceImpl extends DataLoaderService{
    //initialization code
    public Person loadPerson(PredicatesType somePredicate){
        Person person = //get person using predicates expression
        //"delazy" contacts in transaction scope
        person.getContacts();
        return person;
    }
}
```

Architecturally, it would be better, in such a service, to have mapping to DTOs and return DTO instances instead of entities.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one way to solve the problem by using `@JsonIgnore` annotation along with **fethType.LAZY**

```
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String rno;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Contact contact;

    // Getters and setters
}

public class Contact {
    private long id;
    private String info;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Person> persons;
}
```