# Problems with Lazy Loading in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

first post here.  Hope to not get bashed

I'm trying to build an app using Springboot.  I'm using JpaRepository to access the MySQL database.  I've been having this problem when I request to get all Building entities.

I know that this error can be disabled in the application.properties but I want to know where have I done wrong and how to fix it.

Here is the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.aov.buildingapp.common.response.BaseResponse["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.aov.buildingapp.model.building.Building["apartments"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->org.aov.buildingapp.model.apartment.Apartment$HibernateProxy$d8LWlA1P["$$_hibernate_interceptor"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Here are the three entities that are related.  It goes a user has an apartment in a building.

Building:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Table(name = "building")

public class Building {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "id_building")
private int id;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String direction;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "adminToBuilding")
@JsonManagedReference
private User adminUser;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tenantInBuilding")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<User> tenants;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "apartmentInBuilding")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Apartment> apartments;

}
```

Apartment:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Table(name = "apartment")
public class Apartment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "id_apartment")
private int id;

@Column
private int floor;

@Column
private String num;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "apartmentInBuilding", referencedColumnName = "id_building")
@JsonBackReference
private Building apartmentInBuilding;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tenantInApartment")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<User> tenantsInApartment;

}
```

User:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
int id;

@Column
String first_name;

@Column
String last_name;

@Column
String email;

@Column
String password;

@Nullable
@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "adminToBuilding", referencedColumnName = "id_building")
@JsonBackReference
private Building adminToBuilding;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "tenantInBuilding", referencedColumnName = "id_building")
@JsonBackReference
private Building tenantInBuilding;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "tenantInApartment", referencedColumnName = "id_apartment")
@JsonBackReference
private Apartment tenantInApartment;

@Column
private int country_code;

@Column
private String mobile_telephone;

@Column
private String document_type;

@Column
private String document_number;

@Column
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserRoles role;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/58490797/175554 ?

Comment: @özkanpakdil Yes, but the error I get is when I request all Buildings, not one.

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "shipment", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

use where relation is being create in many cause one to many relation fetching using lazy apply

```
@jsonIgnore annotation 
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

adding at top of the class

adding in application.properties

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

adding dependence in build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.7.0'
```

hope your solution has been solved

Comment: Your solution is not very readable at the moment. 
The code could be formatted using single backticks for inline code or triple backticks if you want to post a multi line piece of code.