# Spring jpa trying to insert multiple time same row

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

So I have class like below
and trying to implement ManyToOne relationship

```
        @Entity(name="request_city_id")
        @Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraints{columnNames={"request_id","cityId"})})
        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @FieldDefault(level=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        public class RequestCityId{
    
                @GenratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="seq_req_city_id")
                @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_req_city_id", allocationSize=1)
                @Column(name="rc_id") 
                @Id
                long id;
                //some other many to one joins
                @ManyToOne
                @JoinColumn(name="request_id")
                Request request;
                String cityId;
                String status;
                RequestCityId(Request req){
                   request= req;}
        }
```

Existing table:

```
        @Entity(name="request")
        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @FieldDefault(level=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        public class Request{
            String frequency
            @GenratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="seq_req_d")
            @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_req_id", allocationSize=1)
            @Column(name="request_id") 
            @Id
            long id;

            @OneToMany(cascade={ PERSIST, MERGE}, mappedBy="request", fetch=EAGER)
            Set<RequestCityId> requestCityIds;
 
    }
```

below is serviceClass:

```
RequestRepository reqRepo; // this class extends crudRespository
public RequestDto merge(RequestDto request){
    Request req= mapper.requestDtoToRequest(request);
    Request enhancedObject = enhanceReq( req);
    Request savedObject = reqRepo.save(enahncedObject);
    return mapper.requestToRequestDto(savedObject)
}

private Request enhanceReq(Request req){
    Set<RequestCityId> requestCityIds= req.getRequestCityIds();
    requestCityIds.foreach(e-> e.setRequest(req));
    return req;
}
```

but when I am running my code it is trying to insert multiple times, due to that I am getting constraint violation, what should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are attaching plain unmanaged POJO to `requestCityIds` which then tries to be persisted (inserted) because those are managed entities meaning you dont have to explicit call `save` to actually update the entity.

In order to avoid this, first persist your object with

`Request savedObject = reqRepo.save(enahncedObject);`

and then use that `savedObject` in your method - which now is a managed proxy

```
private Request enhanceReq(Request saved){
    Set<RequestCityId> requestCityIds= req.getRequestCityIds();
    requestCityIds.foreach(e-> e.setRequest(saved));
    return req;
}
```

should work then. Obviousyly you have to juggle around with invocation order etc but the main problem of multiple inserts will be gone.

Comment: then I need to resave that persisted object right?

Comment: getting **No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor**

Comment: Search how to solve it as it is expected to happen in your case
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415243/1527544