# Injection in custom Validator return null

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, jpa, spring-data-rest

I have already looked in stackoverflow and other websites but found nothing which worked for me.

(Spring boot 3)

Log : Resolved [jakarta.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.]

-> Certainly due to my response from Postman

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "Cannot invoke \"com.laramendez.appweb.repository.ProgrammeRepository.existsByNom(String)\" because \"this.programmeRepository\" is null"
    },
    "message": "HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call."
}
```

**dependencies in pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71416675/19092469 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Réduire code répétitif et source d'erreur (reduce boilerplate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Réduire code répétitif et source d'erreur (reduce boilerplate) -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**nomUniqueValidator**

```
package com.laramendez.appweb.validation.validator;

import com.laramendez.appweb.repository.ProgrammeRepository;
import com.laramendez.appweb.validation.annotation.ProgrammeNomUnique;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@NoArgsConstructor
public class NomUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProgrammeNomUnique, String> {

    private ProgrammeRepository programmeRepository;


    @Autowired
    public NomUniqueValidator(ProgrammeRepository programmeRepository) {
        this.programmeRepository = programmeRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(ProgrammeNomUnique constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String nouveauNom, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        
        return !programmeRepository.existsByNom(nouveauNom);

    }
}
```

**ProgrammeNomUnique**

```
package com.laramendez.appweb.validation.annotation;

import com.laramendez.appweb.validation.validator.NomUniqueValidator;
import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Constraint(validatedBy = NomUniqueValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ProgrammeNomUnique {

        // define default error message
        String message() default "Un programme porte déjà le même nom";

        // define default groups
        public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

        // define default payloads
        public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**ProgrammeRepository**

```
package com.laramendez.appweb.repository;

import com.laramendez.appweb.entity.Programme;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "programmes")
public interface ProgrammeRepository extends JpaRepository<Programme, Integer> {

    boolean existsByNom(String nom);
}
```

I'm using Spring Data Rest, that's why i do not have controller, dao and service.

I do not have nothing interesting in my properties.

[image]

Thanks !

My injection in my custom validator return null. Do someone know why? How to dix it?

**UPDATE:**
I just kept an empty constructor like this with advice from M. Deinum but it still does not work, i have the same error

```
public class NomUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProgrammeNomUnique, String> {

    @Autowired
    private ProgrammeRepository programmeRepository;

    public NomUniqueValidator() {
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ProgrammeNomUnique constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String nouveauNom, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        return !programmeRepository.existsByNom(nouveauNom);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: with advice from daniu I tried but I still have the same issue

```
@Component
public class NomUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProgrammeNomUnique, String> {
//[...]
}

@Service
public class NomUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProgrammeNomUnique, String> {
//[...]
}
```

**UPDATE** : with M. Deinum Advice, does not work

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NomUniqueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ProgrammeNomUnique, String> {

        @Autowired
        private  ProgrammeRepository programmeRepository;


    @Override
    public void initialize(ProgrammeNomUnique constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String nouveauNom, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return !programmeRepository.existsByNom(nouveauNom);

    }
```

- I add @Component to my ProgrammeNomUnique.java

**Question :**
I found a github project which works. I did exactly the same way but it was not working for me... The oly one difference, he used javax imports and i use jakarta imports. I cannot use javax because i'm using SB3, maybe they changed how it works... what do you think?

**HERE** there is my gitHub if you want to see and try with me
-> https://github.com/RaphaelAMAMAM/temp-repo-for-validator

Comment: Because it will be constructed with the default constructor and not the one that does injection.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum, it still does not work, i post my update just below. Could you tell me more about your idea please?

Comment: You do need to annotate your class as `@Component` (or `@Service`) for Spring to autowire (not sure if applicable for validators, but would be surprised if not). I would also recommend declaring the repository `final` and use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Comment: Thanks daniu, I still have the same problem with your advice. Do you have another idea?

Comment: I did M. Deinum ! Sorry I'm not familiar with stackoverflow for now. All updates and questions are in my first post

Comment: YOur last one, why does it have a scope? Also there are no required parameters., so the `@RequiredArgsConstructor` doesn't do anything. As mentioned before make sure it is being picked up. You are linking to a repository but I see nowhere the validator is being used.

Comment: It was because i tried others things but now i deleted it and it still does not work.

My required parameters are in my entity Programme (here https://github.com/RaphaelAMAMAM/temp-repo-for-validator/blob/main/app-web-test/src/main/java/com/laramendez/appweb/entity/Programme.java) 
I don't edit my post to post him because i have this message (There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.)

So, it seems I have my requiredArgsConstructor and my required parameters.
Do you know what I can do more?

Again thank you M. Deinum for your help