# Error thrown: "No serializer found for class java.lang.Long..." from controller while serializing JPA entity containing lazy "many-to-one" property

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, lazy-loading, many-to-one

I am on Spring Boot 2.0.6, where an entity `pet` do have a Lazy many-to-one relationship to another entity `owner`

**Pet entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pets")
public class Pet extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

  @NonNull
  private String name;
  private String birthday;

  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
  @JsonProperty("ownerId")
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private Owner owner;
```

But while submitting a request like `/pets` through a client(eg: PostMan), the controller.get() method run into an exception as is given below:-

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.lang.Long and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.petowner.entity.Pet["ownerId"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
```

**Controller.get implementation**

```
@GetMapping("/pets")
public @ResponseBody List<Pet> get() {
 List<Pet> pets = petRepository.findAll();
 return pets;
}
```

**My observations**

1. Tried to invoke explicitly the getters within `owner` through `pet` to force the lazy-loading from the javaassist proxy object of `owner` within the `pet`. But did not work.

   ```
   @GetMapping("/pets")
   public @ResponseBody List<Pet> get() {
      List<Pet> pets = petRepository.findAll();
      pets.forEach( pet -> pet.getOwner().getId());
      return pets;
   }
   ```
2. Tried as suggested by this stackoverflow answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129212/5107365 to have controller call to delegate to a service bean within the transaction scope to force lazy-loading. But that did not work too.

   ```
   @Service
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public class PetServiceImpl implements PetService {

       @Autowired
       private PetRepository petRepository;

       @Override
       public List<Pet> loadPets() {
           List<Pet> pets = petRepository.findAll();
           pets.forEach(pet -> pet.getOwner().getId());
           return pets;
       }
   ```

   }
3. It works when Service/Controller returning a DTO created out from the entity. Obviously, the reason is JSON serializer get to work with a POJO instead of an ORM entity without any mock objects in it.
4. Changing the entity fetch mode to FetchType.EAGER would solve the problem, but I did not want to change it.

I am curious to know why it is thrown the exception in case of (1) and (2). Those should have forced the explicit loading of lazy objects.

Probably the answer might be connected to the life and scope of that javassist objects got created to maintain the lazy objects. Yet, wondering how would Jackson serializer not find a serializer for a java wrapper type like `java.lang.Long`. Please do rememeber here that the exception thrown did indicate that Jackson serializer got access to `owner.getId` as it recognised the type of the property `ownerId` as `java.lang.Long`.

Any clues would be highly appreciated.

### Edit

The edited part from the accepted answer explains the causes. Suggestion to use a custom serializer is very useful one in case if I don't need to go in DTO's path.

I did a bit of scanning through the Jackson sources to dig down to the root causes. Thought to share that too.

Jackson caches most of the serialization metadata on first use. Logic related to the use case in discussion starts at this method `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(Collection<?> value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider)`. And, the respective code snippet is:-

[image]

The statement `serializer = _findAndAddDynamic(serializers, cc, provider)` at Line #140 trigger the flow to assign serializers for `pet`-level properties while skipping `ownerId` to be later processed through `serializer.serializeWithType` at line #147.

Assigning of serializers is done at `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.resolve(SerializerProvider provider)` method. The respective snippet is shown below:-

[image]

Serializers are assigned at line #340 only for those properties which are confirmed as `final` through the check at line #333.

When `owner` comes here, its proxied properties are found to be of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType`. Had this associated entity been loaded `eagerly`, the proxied properties obviously won't be there. Instead, original properties would be found with the values that are typed with final classes like Long, String, etc. (just like the `pet` properties).

Wondering why can't Jackson address this from their end by using the getter's type instead of using that of the proxied property. Anyway, that could be a different topic to discuss :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the way that Hibernate (internally what spring boot uses for JPA by default) hydrates objects. A lazy object is not loaded until some parameter of the object is requested. Hibernate returns a proxy which delegates to the dto after firing queries to hydrate the objects.

In your scenario, loading OwnerId does not help because it is the key via which you are referencing the owner object i.e. the OwnerId is already present in the Pet object, so the hydration will not take place.

In both 1 and 2, you have not actually loaded the owner object, so when Jackson tries to serialize it at the controller level it fails. In 3 and 4, the owner object has been loaded explicitly, which is why Jackson does not run into any issues.

If you want 2 to work then load some parameter of owner, other than id, and hibernate will hydrate the object, and then jackson will be able to serialize it.

**Edited Answer**

The problem here is with the default Jackson serializer. This inspects the class returned and fetches the value of each attribute via reflection. In the case of hibernate entities, the object returned is a delegator proxy class in which all parameters are null, but all getters are redirected to the contained instance. When the object is inspected, the values of each attribute are still null, which is defaulted to an error as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862483/spring-and-jackson-how-to-disable-fail-on-empty-beans-through-responsebody/28862597)

So basically, you need to tell jackson how to serialize this object. You can do so by creating a serializer class

```
public class OwnerSerializer extends StdSerializer<Owner> {

    public OwnerSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public OwnerSerializer(Class<Owner> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Owner value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.getId());
        jgen.writeStringField("firstName", value.getFirstName());
        jgen.writeStringField("lastName", value.getLastName());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

And setting it as the default serializer for the object

```
@JsonSerialize(using = OwnerSerializer.class)
public class Owner extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
```

Alternatively, you can create a new Object of type Owner from the proxy class, manually populate it and set it in the response.

It is a little roundabout, but as a general practice you should not expose your DTO's externally anyway. The controller/domain should be decoupled from the storage layer.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. However, it threw up the exception even when I tried to hydrate using `firstName` instead of `id` as `pets.forEach(pet -> pet.getOwner().getFirstName());`.  I tried this from both the controller and service without success.

Comment: Explicit invocation on non-id getter on lazy object should have resulted in hydration. But did not find it happen so. Also noticed through debugger mode, that the javassist proxy objects within `pet` for `owner` is active even at the time of jackson serialization. I wonder if it has got anything to do the observed behaviour.

Comment: The proxy is what will be returned. That is expected. Via the debugger, try accessing all the attributes in the object outside the service and inside the service. That'll give you an idea where there's an issue.

Comment: Been able to access the attributes through proxy methods via debugger without any issues. But, serialization continues to throw up exception on java.lang.Long which is the type of ownerId. I have posted my code at https://bitbucket.org/rajpk/petserver for anyone to have a better picture. My whole curiosity is to know why the explicit invocation of non-id setter of lazy object is not helping serialization with itself (without the use of dto or so).

Comment: got the sample working and added an edited answer with the code snippets

Comment: Fantastic. thanks a lot. That pretty much explains it. Will mark it as the answer. I did a bit of research through jackson codebase. And, as you said, it wouldn't find a serializer for the properties associated with the proxied instance, just because there is a code snippet in there could assign built-in serializers only for the final classes, where as the proxied properties are of type "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType". Will add the reference to the code snippet as a separate answer.