# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.2, hibernate-6.x

I already went through: [Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693110/could-not-write-json-infinite-recursion-stackoverflowerror-nested-exception) & many links like this. I am using `Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and Data JPA and Postgres` example

This is my source code: https://github.com/JavaHelper/issue-jackson-boot

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.example.demo.entity.StockDailyRecord["stock"]->com.example.demo.entity.Stock$HibernateProxy$f8byIJ39["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:313) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar:2.9.9]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:225) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Stock.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
public class Stock extends BaseEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer stockId;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String stockCode;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String stockName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<StockDailyRecord> stockDailyRecords = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "sBuilder")
    public Stock(Integer stockId, String stockCode, String stockName, Set<StockDailyRecord> stockDailyRecords,
            Instant createdDate, Instant lastUpdateDate, String createUser, String lastUpdateUser) {
        super(createdDate, lastUpdateDate, createUser, lastUpdateUser);
        this.stockId = stockId;
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.stockDailyRecords = stockDailyRecords;
    }
}
```

StockDailyRecord.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_daily_record")
public class StockDailyRecord extends BaseEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RECORD_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer recordId;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_OPEN", precision = 6)
    private Float priceOpen;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_CLOSE", precision = 6)
    private Float priceClose;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_CHANGE", precision = 6)
    private Float priceChange;

    @Column(name = "VOLUME")
    private Long volume;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Stock stock;

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "sdBuilder")
    public StockDailyRecord(Integer recordId, Float priceOpen, Float priceClose, Float priceChange, Long volume,
            Stock stock, Instant createdDate, Instant lastUpdateDate, String createUser, String lastUpdateUser) {
        super(createdDate, lastUpdateDate, createUser, lastUpdateUser);
        this.recordId = recordId;
        this.priceOpen = priceOpen;
        this.priceClose = priceClose;
        this.priceChange = priceChange;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}
```

BaseEntity.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class BaseEntity {
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "lastUpdateDate", nullable = false)
    private Instant lastUpdateDate;

    @Column(name = "createUser", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String createUser;

    @Column(name = "lastUpdateUser", length = 50)
    private String lastUpdateUser;
}
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52656517/6413377)?

Comment: @pirho - Related solution also not working in my case. Is there anything that needs to be done with the latest version of boot 2.1.6?

Comment: @duffymo - Its not duplicate issues, so read question again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656517/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-bytebuddy-bytebuddyinterc?rq=1

Comment: Two different answers cite that as the solution.  I don't see it in your question.

Comment: @duffymo - Link you shared says OR between `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) `, thats where the confusion come. We should be using both at the same time. Also, pleople have provided more comments below that solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how this is working, but mixed of two things are working nicely. Took reference from here: [Great Link](https://grokonez.com/json/resolve-json-infinite-recursion-problems-working-jackson)

I added both `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` and `@JsonIgnore` Can not preserve the Bidirectional-Relationships after deserialization.

Here is my class now

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
public class Stock extends BaseEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer stockId;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String stockCode;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String stockName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<StockDailyRecord> stockDailyRecords = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "sBuilder")
    public Stock(Integer stockId, String stockCode, String stockName, Set<StockDailyRecord> stockDailyRecords,
            Instant createdDate, Instant lastUpdateDate, String createUser, String lastUpdateUser) {
        super(createdDate, lastUpdateDate, createUser, lastUpdateUser);
        this.stockId = stockId;
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.stockDailyRecords = stockDailyRecords;
    }
}
```

Note: Since it's `@ManyToOne` Relationship, so we cant not excepts `StockDailyRecord` from `Stock`, it will always be like getting `Stock` data from `StockDailyRecord`

You can also look **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)**

This is great: **[My Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102996/how-to-serialize-a-json-containing-lazy-associations/51129161#51129161)**

Answer (score 1):

You might ignore properties **hibernateLazyInitializer** and **handler**, well this issue is when you have entities that are loaded lazily before the serialization then the entities get loaded fully. Put on the head of class that causes this issue.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Comment: This alone doesn't works in my case. You can test with my source code share in the post, git link